# Add custom MIME type in System.Web.MimeMapping programmatically

Tags: .net, mime-types

I am using `MimeMapping` class from `System.Web` assembly to get mime types from file extensions.

But in case of `.HEIC` extensions it is returning mime type as `application/octet-stream`. But the original mime type associated with this extension is `image/heic`.

`MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("something.HEIC")//returning application/octet-stream`

Do `MimeMapping` class provides any api to add new mappings so that I can get the correct mime-type?

Comment: Is this .NET Framework or Core? [Here's the Framework source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/MimeMapping.cs) - it looks like it has a built-in list (that doesn't have HEIC) or can take mappings from applicationHost.config somehow. Worst case you could use reflection to find the `_mappingDictionary` private static field and see if you can call AddMapping on it (also by reflection).

Comment: IIS will usually use the registry, though: check HKLM\Software\Classes\.heic exists and has a ContentType value. I'd assume .NET would import mappings from there somehow?

Comment: @Rup the idea of using reflection is great. I think i will try that way and if succeeds I will post it in here

Comment: @Rup heic doesn't exists in the 'HKLM\Software\Classes\'

Comment: OK, you could try creating that then, and then hopefully IIS will pick up the content type automatically? You can either try exporting the key from a machine that has it e.g. an up-to-date Windows 10 install, or just create a new key with a single string value 'Content Type'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tip by Rup and reflection. I'd created a method which can be used to add custom mime-types to the private static variable which MimeMapping class uses for resolving mime types.

```
        public static void RegisterMimeTypes(IDictionary<string, string> mimeTypes)
        {
            if (mimeTypes == null || mimeTypes.Count == 0)
                return;
            var field = typeof(System.Web.MimeMapping).GetField("_mappingDictionary",
                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);

            var currentValues = field.GetValue(null);
            var add = field.FieldType.GetMethod("AddMapping",
                      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var mime in mimeTypes)
            {
                add.Invoke(currentValues, new object[] { mime.Key, mime.Value });
            }

        }
```

Now you can register your list of custom mime-types on the application startup like below

```
    var mimeTypes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { ".heic", "image/heic"},
        {".extn", "custom/mime" }
    };

    RegisterMimeTypes(mimeTypes);
```

***Example***

`MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("filename.heic")// will return image/heic`